# getPixel32 is inaccurate

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

```
function encodeBmp(s:String){
    s = Base64.Encode(s);
    var width:Number = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(s.length/4));
    var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(width,width,true,0x00000000);
    var pos:Number=0; //track position in string
    for(var x:Number=0;x<width;x++){
        for(var y:Number=0;y<width;y++){
            var col="0x";
            for(var i:Number=0;i<4;i++){
                col+=getHex(s.charAt(pos));
                pos++;
            }
            bmp.setPixel32(x,y,col);
            trace(col + " > 0x" + bmp.getPixel32(x,y).toString(16));
        }
    }
    return bmp.clone();
}
```

Basically, the trace statement returns this:

```
0x56326868 > 0x56326868
0x64434270 > 0x64424270
0x63794230 > 0x63794331
...
```

Why is the result of getPixel32 different from that of the set value, and how can I resolve this?

EDIT: getPixel is accurate, but doesn't have the extra bit that get/setPixel32 does... I would prefer to have more data per pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're Base64 encoding a String to store it in a BitmapData. I hope you didn't know that, or are ashamed.

Anyway, here is what I see happening:

First, if you type `col` as a `String`, you'll get a compile error on `setPixel32`, because it's expecting a `uint`.

Now, we can ignore all the looping and hex strings to get some simple code to reproduce the problem.

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1, 1);
bitmapData.setPixel32(0, 0, 1682129520);
trace(bitmapData.getPixel32(0, 0));
```

By using an int literal, we can see that it's not a problem with type coercion, but something inside of BitmapData. This makes sense, since BitmapData is intended to store graphics data, so storing the graphics in a way that is graphically similar but not exact is fine.

You're probably seeing the side-effects of pre-multiplied alpha in Flash. This would also explain why you don't see any problems with `getPixel` and `setPixel`.

You can read more about it here: http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000665.php

So how do you fix the problem? **Use the correct data type**. A `ByteArray` is designed to store binary data.

Comment: I am, in fact, ashamed. The reason for such madness is the embedding of a very large text file with UTF-8 characters that would normally crash the compiler if added by normal means (it absolutely NEEDS to be embedded). I would use a ByteArray and a much more elegant solution if this were in fact AS3, and I had that luxury. Based on your answer, I understand there is no solution with get/setPixel32 due to the pre-multiplied alpha. Thanks for taking the time to try to answer a question about a deprecated language.

Comment: Haha, it makes much more sense now if you're limited to AS2. In that case, I guess `getPixel` is a reasonable solution.